# Twitter OAuth keeps redirecting to https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=XYZ

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I think i've implemented twitter oauth correctly, but everytime a user clicks to login via twitter on my site, he is redirected to https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=XYZ where he is prompted to authorize my application **again**.

My source code is based on:
http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html which itself seems based on https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master/twitteroauth

```
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
// Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken($site_url.'getTwitterData.php');

// Saving them into the session

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

// If everything goes well..
if ($twitteroauth->http_code == 200) {
    // Let's generate the URL and redirect
    $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
    header('Location: ' . $url);
} else {
    // It's a bad idea to kill the script, but we've got to know when there's an error.
    die('The Twitter service is currently not responding. Please try again later.');
}
?>
```

In twitteroauth.php, I earlier had:

```
   function accessTokenURL()  { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'; }
   function authenticateURL() { return 'https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'; }
   function authorizeURL()    { return 'https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize'; }
   function requestTokenURL() { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'; }
```

but then tried:

```
   function accessTokenURL()  { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'; }
   function authenticateURL() { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'; }
   function authorizeURL()    { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'; }
   function requestTokenURL() { return 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'; }
```

as well - but no luck.

Comment: do you do `session_start()` or are the sessions automatically started everytime?

Comment: I'm doing a session_start(); but that line is located elsewhere in an included file... (above the quoted code)

Comment: What is it that you are expecting to happen?

Comment: @abraham  - are you abraham of https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/ fame? :) :) My app connects to twitter but then the user is prompted every time to authorize the application - I'm not sure why that's happening. What can I test to diagnose this more?

Comment: @abraham - help needed! :) Surely it can't expect the user to authorize the application every time!

Comment: @matt74tm if the user is authenticated with twitter.com, they application is listed on https://twitter.com/account/connections as authorized and you send the user to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate then the user should be redirected back to the callback_url seamlessly. If all three are true then there might be a bug in the Twitter API.

Comment: Do you have an example site up somewhere I can try it? And yes I am that abraham.

Comment: Hi @abraham - can I email you somewhere? or can you drop me a line at: mySOusername@gmail.com

Comment: @abraham - sent you an email about 2 days back or so...

Comment: @matt74tm Sorry about the delay. I'm behind on email. I'm convinced it is a bug with Twitter API and that you should email api@twitter.com

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-development-talk/-5yaRBzk6Ac

Comment: @abraham - thanks - didnt see a clear answer though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: The application's permission level as set on twitter.com did not match what we were doing.

Message from Twitter:

> If you use the oauth/authenticate
>   method without setting either the
>   force_login or screen_name parameter,
>   Twitter will redirect back to your
>   site as long as the user is logged
>   into Twitter and already has a valid
>   OAuth access token for your
>   application. If you have recently
>   switched your application's permission
>   level (for example, from read/write to
>   read/write/DM), this redirect won't
>   happen since a new permission is being
>   requested. If this doesn't help, you
>   may also want to post about this in
>   our developer talk group:
>   http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk
>   . Our API engineering team interacts
>   with developers here on a regular
>   basis.